# How do I install PrusaSlicer from github?

Tags: github

I'm trying to get the PrusaSlicer software here https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer.git But I'm very new to Linux and I don't know how to install it. I've tried to run the appimage file, but it says `error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I'd like to have this program upgrade with `sudo apt upgrade`, but I don't know how to install it correctly for it to do that as well.

I don't have a clue here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the required library `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` by running

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two preconditions if you want to update a software package via `apt`. First, the software's publisher needs to build and release the software as *debian packages*, which can be recognized by the file ending `deb`. Secondly, the publisher needs to operate a *repository*. That's basically a url from where you can download `deb` packages, plus some metadata like which version is the newest and so forth.

`apt update` and `apt upgrade` (or `apt full-upgrade`) basically walk through the list of repositories you have configured on your system. For each, they check whether there are newer versions of `deb` packages you have installed, and offer to install those newer versions.

The team behind PrusaSlicer does not seem to offer their software as debian packages, and they don't seem to operate a repository. So you can't use `apt` with that software. There's [an issue](https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/issues/2608) (which is the Github term for "support ticket" or "bug report") suggesting to basically add a repository, but we'll have to wait and see when or if they're going to do that.

As far as the error message from the AppImage package is concerned, packages (debian packages, AppImage packages, ...) typically don't contain all code necessary to run the program. For example, PrusaSlicer didn't reinvent the wheel and write their own graphics code to draw windows, buttons and the like on the screen. They're using an existing *library* for that, in this case the graphics toolkit [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK). Obviously, GTK needs to be installed on your machine so PrusaSlicer can use it. That's what the error message is complaining about, "I try to use the library `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`, but I can't find it". pilot6 already mentioned in his answer which debian package from the Ubuntu repositories you need to install to get the library.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail here. I've learned a few things reading your answer.

Comment: To add to this, be careful in adding packages via `apt` that developers say to add.  A lot of them carelessly say, "Install this X Dev packages, or build-essentials, etc." Don't.  Dev packages and build essentials often are not vetted for security patches because they are dev packages not intended for production. Also, these Dev/Build-essentials packages usually expose a far larger attack surface if you do get compromised, allowing the attacker to compile and access far more tools on your system.